# Как можно увеличить скорость записи на SSD Samsung(системно)?

Tags: windows

Нужно записывать на SSD диск изображения, очень много и очень быстро, на данный момент достигается скорость 2.4Gb на запись (хотя Samsung Magician тест показывает 3Gb), но появилась теория, что если перед процедурой записи на диске принудительно запускать оптимизацию и триминг (может еще что то), то это позволит еще дополнительно увеличить скорость записи.

То, что мне удалось найти это все связано с настройками системы и самого диска (то есть это не, что то, что можно запускать это либо включено либо выключено)

вот как тут

```
IDE vs AHCI Mode. ...
Confirm TRIM is Running. ...
Avoid and Disable Disk Defragmenter. ...
Disable Indexing Service/Windows Search. ...
Enable Write Caching for SSDs. ...
Update Drivers and Firmware for Your SSD. ...
Optimize or Disable Page File for SSDs. ...
Turn Off System Restore.
```

В общем вопрос в том, как можно увеличить скорость записи на SSD Samsung(системно)?

Comment: если разрешить кеш для записи, то данные будут как будто записаны, но по факту они ещё до диска не дойдут. 
А какую конкретно задачу пытаетесь решить? сделать с обычного ssd новый nvme?

Comment: @KoVadim кстати мне кажется, что у нас на самом деле nvme стоит(нужно проверить), но дело не в этом, итогда бывает так, что скорость записи падает до 1.2 и (как я сказал) есть теория, что нужно как то предварительно запускать оптимазацию и трим, как будто это должно все привести в порядок и подготовить к записи и потом начинать саму запись. Но я не уверен, что двигаюсь в правильном направлении, поэтому вот решил поинтерисоваться:)

Comment: скорость может падать по куче причин. например, потому что диск делает "оптимизацию данных". Но Вы так и не ответили на мой вопрос - зачем это делать? что бы продать диск подороже?

Comment: @KoVadim нет, как я написал, у меня есть программа, которая пишет очень много и очень быстро, это видео и вот для примера, программа справляется хорошо с записью в 45 fps, но иногда я замечаю, что бафер начинает заполняться и когда я проверяю скорость я вижу 1.2 (хотя обычно ~2). Вот я и пытаюсь понять в чем может быть причина. А как понять, что диск делает оптимизацию? Это где то отображается (может в TaskManager)?

Comment: SLC-кэш заканчивается небось...

Comment: Да, вполне может быть и диск перекладывает в TLC.  Что делать? Купить быстрее диск, сделать рейд,